# Parsing date after calling sp in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have the following issue:

How can i parse my date comming from MSSQL server in format `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` and i need to parse into `dd/MM/yyyy` format in .net. I tried doing the following and other formats but i cant make it work:

```
    dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Here is my code when i call the database:

```
        var con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetDates", con);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

            dia.DataSource = dt;
            dia.DataTextField = "Dates";
            dia.DataValueField = "Dates";

            dia.DataBind();
        }
```

Thx all

Comment: Please include the parsing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the [DataTextFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the dropdown. I believe you can se it like:

```
dia.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
```